# git alias for recent checkout branches

Tags: git, alias

I recently found this command to get a list of most recent 10 checked out branches.

```
git reflog | egrep -io 'moving from ([^[:space:]]+)' | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | head -n10
```

I wanted to create an alias for this call "git recent", but when I try to run the config command it throws an error. "*event not found*"

```
git config --global alias.recent 'reflog | egrep -io 'moving from ([^[:space:]]+)' | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | head -n10'
```

Is there anyway to get this complicated command as a alias. If anyone knows how to it up as a alias that excepts a number parameter would be greatly appreciated as well. The **-n10** at the end of the command states how many branches to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for anyone happens upon this question and this command interests them. I determined a way to this.

For one I gave up trying to do this using the git config command. I instead opened the git config file itself and added alias that way.
[Adding git aliases](https://githowto.com/aliases)

Second I determined my script was correct I just had to add it as a function. *my_alias = "!f() { 〈your complex command〉 }; f"*
[How to add Advanced alias template in git](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/10/advanced-git-aliases/)

Here is an example of my alias.

```
[alias]
    recent = "!f() { git reflog | egrep -io 'moving from ([^[:space:]]+)' | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | head -n${1-10}; }; f"
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this is what I do as well—well, this, or avoid using complex aliases. :-) The problem is that complex aliases require using the `!` character and a lot of quoting, and shells like to eat `!` characters and various kinds of quoting. Getting them to survive the shell and into the alias file is an unnecessary headache, since you can just run `git config --global --edit` or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Though a bit different from what you asked for, if might make more sense to find out branches that have been changed recently.

In this case `git branch` actually has a `--sort=<key>` option, which can print the branches sorted by the given key, e.g.:

```
git branch --sort=-committerdate -v
```

This will sort the branches by `committerdate`, but reversed as specified by the prefix `-` as in `-committerdate`. And also print the latest commit, to setup an alias, such as `br`, run this command:

```
git config --global alias.br "branch --sort=-committerdate -v"
```

See [git-branch manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).

Comment: I like this as well, but doesn't exactly fit my use case. Where I work there are four developers that collaborate in a single repository that contains a dozen Drupal multisites on a daily basis. Because of this setup we have well over 1000 branches most of which are named similarly. We each work on multiple projects in a week so I just needed a way of seeing only a list of branches that I checked out recently so I can easily multitask and maneuver though my work. I think your command will show me their work as well, which very cool but overwhelming when I can't remember what I named a branch.

Comment: Thank you though, I think I can find a way to use this as well.

Answer (score 0):

"event not found" comes from your bash which interprets the `!` in the command line ... you mixed up your single quotes in the second command. It should be clear how to fix this; say if you have trouble figuring it out...

Double quotes also don't work:

```
> echo '!'
!
> echo "!"
bash: !: event not found
```

Hint: you can make the outer quotes `'` and then use `"` inside, this will escape the complete command including the `!` from bash.

I don't have time now to make you that statement, but I'm sure you'll figure it out in no time... ;)

Comment: I added double quotes instead if that's what you are saying the problem is, and i'm still getting the same error. ----
    git config --global alias.recent "reflog | egrep -io "moving from ([^[:space:]]+)" | awk '{ print $3 }' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | head -n10"